# Why are we getting "gd:extendedProperty count limit exceeded" error?

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

We're trying to update a number of Google contacts, using the {thin} feed projection

PUT https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{user}/thin/{id}

but we're getting the following errors from Google contacts API:

```
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>invalid</code>
  <internalReason>gd:extendedProperty count limit exceeded: 10</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

When using the {thin} feed projection extended properties are not even loaded or manipulated, according to the API reference: "thin - No gd:extendedProperty elements are returned/updated".

This looks like the API bug.

@SGC, the answer does not seem to be relevant. We use {thin} project to avoid loading/updating any extended properties. Why does the API complain this way?

@Google can someone help with this issue?

Comment: In the documentation, its mentioned that, if you use thin property No gd:extendedProperty elements are returned/updated. Check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference

Comment: It does sound like a bug, but it would be great to have more information about when this error occurs. For instance, do all contact updates generate this error of just select ones? Do the contacts that generate this error have more than 10 extended properties defined?

Comment: I wonder if this has been fixed finally? Last time this error was seen in our logs was end of September. This was definitely happening only for a few contacts out of many that a user had.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, its mentioned that, if you use thin property **No** gd:extendedProperty elements are returned/updated. Check this [link](http://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer. Yes, we use that projection specifically so that we don't have to deal with any extended properties. We don't set any extended properties but our updates fail with the message that clearly refers to the extended properties: gd:extendedProperty count limit exceeded: 10

Comment: This keeps happening when using the 'thin' projection. Can someone help?